# How can I understand 十二建除择日 in Feng Shui?

Tags: translation, meaning

Or if you can indicate a site or book in English about Feng Shui that talks about this.

> 十二建除择日又可称为十二建星择日，这十二颗星分别为：建、除、满、平、定、执、破、危、成、收、开、闭。

Can someone please help me translate?

Answer (score 3):

> It states that 12 stars (or gods) take turns to rule each day in an endless cycle

well, the description of “take turns to rule each day” is  . . . **imprecise**. when month changes, a “建除” would be repeated

the rule of assigning “建除” is based upon the earthly branches of the day and the month; then, the trickiest is, according to the fortune-telling calendar, month changes when it’s an odd solar term (節交 立春，驚蟄，清明 . . .)

eg

| date | 干支 | 建除 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-04 | 壬寅年乙巳月戊子日 | 危 |
| 2022-06-05 | 壬寅年乙巳月己丑日 | 成 |
| 2022-06-06 | 壬寅年**丙午月**庚寅日・**節交芒種** | **成** |
| 2022-06-07 | 壬寅年丙午月辛卯日 | 收 |

| date | 干支 | 建除 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 | 壬寅年丙午月己未日 | 除 |
| 2022-07-06 | 壬寅年丙午月庚申日 | 滿 |
| 2022-07-07 | 壬寅年**丁未月**辛酉日・**節交小暑** | **滿** |
| 2022-07-08 | 壬寅年丁未月壬戌日 | 平 |

https://fate.windada.com/cgi-bin/calendar

have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

十二建除择日 means:  [12 Day Stars Method Of Date Selection](https://www.fengshuied.com/12-day-stars)

> The 12-day stars (十二值日星) is one of the most basic methods of selecting auspicious and inauspicious dates to undertake activities. In some circles, it is also called the 12 day officers (**建除**十二神).

> It states that 12 stars (or gods) take turns to rule each day in an endless cycle.

> With an underlying meaning to each star, it determines what particular day would be most suitable to take on or avoid certain activities.

> It must be noted that the 12-day stars method of date selection is a subset of a bigger and wider Chinese metaphysical concept known as the Huang Dao Ji Ri (黄道吉日).

> A dozen stars are individually named according to 12 types of chi and correlate to the 12 animal zodiac signs.

It is called 十二建除 because 建除 are the first two characters on the list of 12

You can read the rest on [the site](https://www.fengshuied.com/12-day-stars)

Comment: Very thanks ! ヾ(≧▽≦*)o

Answer (score 1):

> **十二建除择日**又可称为**十二建星择日**，这十二颗星分别为：建、除、满、平、定、执、破、危、成、收、开、闭。

Here is a brief explanation of "十二建除择日". Since to-the-point translation is a daunting task, only the Chinese version is provided here.

In order to understand 建除, we need to define 建星 first:

- 十二建星即是每月的月建，正月建寅、二月建卯、三月建辰……依此类推。**“建”乃一月之主，所以从“建”起。“建”之后为“除”，謂“除旧布新”**。十二建除取"建"和"除"代表這十二颗星的輪回.
- 择日就是"看日子"或"挑日子", - 選吉避邪 (pick a good date, avoid the bad date).

Hope this helps.

http://www.zhfengshuiw.com/4533.html

Answer (score 0):

Date selection is one of the professional specialist branches of esoteric knowledge related to the traditional astronomic “science” with the application of the principles from IChing, namely Yin Yang & Wu Xing (五行）5 elements). Other related branches are numerous such as traditional Chinese medicine, Fengshui, various methods of divination, etc. In all these branches or systems, the common fundamental system is the application of 10 heavy stems (HS) 十天干：甲乙丙丁戊己庚辛壬癸 jia yi bing ding wu ji geng xin ren gui and 12 earthly branches (EB) 十二地支：子丑寅卯辰巳午未申酉戌亥 zi chou yin mao chen si wu wei shen you xu hai.  There are 60 combinations of heavy stem-earthly branch HS-EB pairs (with Yang HS paired only to Yang EB, Yin HS paired to Yin EB) called 60 Jia-zi 六十甲子，甲being the 1st HS, 子the 1st EB. Time and space (directions) are always represented by these HS-EB pairs. Eg.this year of 2022 is the year ren yin 壬寅年。According to Chinese Agricultural Calendar, each year starts with the onset of Spring 立春 （usually in late January or February in Gregorian Calendar) which would be represented by the month of yin寅月，the 1st month of the year, etc.

“十二建除择日排法

十二建除择日的排法，是以月建开始排起。如农历正月建寅，就是以正月第一个寅日为建，次日为除，再次日为满，以此类推。农历二月建卯，就以二月第一个卯日为建，次日为除，再次日为满以此类推。三月辰日起建，四月巳日起建，五月午日起建，六月未日起建，七月申日起建，八月酉日起建，九月戌日起建，十月亥日起建，十一月子日起建，十二月丑日起建。”

The 12 “stars”: 建、除、满、平、定、执、破、危、成、收、开、闭 was created in line with probably the pattern of thinking as in the creation of 12 EBs, giving each of the 12 stars a name and an inherent value of “auspiciousness”.  The rule for the assignment of each star to a day would be : for the 1st month of yin寅月，the 1st day of yin,寅日would be assigned day of jian建日，the following day would be day of chu 除日，etc. In the 2nd month, the month of mao卯月，the 1st day of mao卯日would be assigned as day of jian建日, the following day the day of chu除日。For 辰月（三月）,the first 辰日be建日，the next day be 除日，etc.For date selection, one could check against the traditional rhymes handed from generation to generation:

建除十二神择日吉凶歌

建日相逢造葬凶，颠狂乱舞破家风。

行嫁出行上任吉，教牛教马此事通。

建日可谋本为事，若改前为莫再逢。

总计建除平收日，出兵斩破大有功。

遇娶妻并造葬，求官上任阻前程。

经商出行及移徙，兴工动土楚战秦。

疗病捉贼除服好，宜合帷帐除邪精。

斩毒断蚁塞鼠穴，解释冤愆一切灵。

贪酷官吏恶人类，除日告之问假真。

满宜造仓并作柜，诸事为之大吉昌。

婚姻结义完全好，一园春色百花香。

古之满日土瘟是，架造可为葬不良。

不宜栽种并服药，开凿池溏鱼满江。

平宜收盗及收瘟，剥削除灾百事亨。

又宜行嫁及教畜，遇伐逢金断贼根。

造葬埋之俱平过，余皆守分及高增。

定可冠带及安床，余作虽为事不良。

招惹官非名死气，纵逢吉曜也平常。

造葬若逢此定日，好事生来却有妨。

执有威仪总势权，得遇之星出大贤。

捕贼擒凶称妙手，任教捆绑百心寒。

若合宝义专好宿，用之大吉有威权。

破日造葬嫁娶凶，诸事交关无好终。

说合不和谋不就，经商买卖求不通。

纵合宝义专好宿，用之亦在破败中。

疗病针灸皆可用，秀士赴考夺天工。

危日登高及行船，日良宿好却多险。

作事交关全得好，所谋百事独称先。

危日安床亦可许，造屋迁移亦不安。

成日无不诸事谐，造葬分明待贵来。

娶妻必定生贵子，求名求利亦快哉。

若问来年新旧事，结冤结仇不须裁。

收日娶妻埋葬吉，又好出行及买庄。

若遇宝义专好宿，百为皆美及作商。

架造不宜用收日，阳宅宜显阴宅藏。

开日相逢百事昌，天开生气到生方。

最宜架造生贵子，开门放水进田庄。

嫁娶迁徙出行吉，求名求利喜增光。

闭日埋葬及藏宝，遇此为之终到老。

六畜栏枋造亦宜，架造医目最不好。

施针下灸不当为，塞路合帐称巧妙。

又宜娶妇不妄动，守静闺门留好名。

Or check the Specialist Calendar:

[image]

to  determine whether a particular day is auspicious for say marriage or commencing construction work of a house etc. or not